# What do i do how do I get my truck back or paid for everything that I've lost

Tags: california, police, civil-legal-system, forgery, car-title

Someone(ex roommate who i had sexual relations with) forged my signature on a bill of sale and stole my truck  i Called to report it and the police won't do nothing since the truck is no longer in my name... And prior to that she had tried to steal my truck and i called the cops she had the newest title and i had the oldest and the police told her it's a civil matter .... Then she must've got a key made with the new title and she was able to steal it and the police wouldn't do anything one because there was already open case through DMV for her getting the title in my name but nothing came about it the da wouldn't accept the case and said civil but  hasn't she not committed a felony so I'm confused here this is not justice who do i speak to for help all around

Comment: Get a lawyer. We are not your Legal Clinic, we can't give you Legal Avice.

Answer (score 2):

As you were told by several people: It's a civil case. You get a lawyer and take her to court. The lawyer will tell you what to do to get your truck back. And there might be evidence coming out that she did commit some crime.